# "Could Not Find or Load Main Class..."

Tags: java, classloader, javac

I am new to Java and I got this book to help me start.
I have successfully compiled Hello.java using "`javac Hello.java`".
Now it says to type in "`java Hello`" and I am getting "`Could not load of find main class Hello`". I have tried to find out how to fix it before but all the answers are complicated and confusing. If someone could explain how to fix this, that would be awesome.

Comment: Make sure a) the sourcefile is indeed `Hello.java` (as opposed to `hello.java`) same for class file (`Hello.class`). Furthermore, make sure you have capitalized Hello in the source code.

Comment: set the CLASSPATH variable and your problem will be solved

Comment: Can you paste the code,make sure java is case sensitive.Class name must match during compiling and running it

Answer (score 1):

The problem appears to be of [CLASSPATH](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html).

### Solution 1

Add the path of your directory where you have compiled your class to the CLASSPATH variable in Environment Variables.

### Solution 2

Every time you run the program add the current folder and libraries you are referencing in the classpath using `-classpath`. eg:

```
java -classpath .;lib/referenced-libs.jar my.package.MainClass
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the main method with exactly this syntax is present in the Hello.java file:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // your code will go here...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should check if the hello.class file is present in the folder. java runs these .class files. These files are created on successful compilation.

Comment: He should probably copy paste the code here for us to be able to help him better.

Comment: I am sorry. I thought you were the question asker. made an edit. sorry :)